# Code for Identifying a Single letter?

Tags: java, android

Hi there I am a bit of a noob at programming but I want to create an IF statement , whether or not a textview , (which i have already referenced) contains a letter in side of it and only that letter for example I want to change any textview which has a "1" in it whats the code? this is what I have got can some one please help me complete it?

```
if ("!".contains(stuff.getText()) {
    stuff.setText("Incorrect Symbol");
}else {

}
```

I know that I can use the keyboard to control what can be entered but I would prefer that someone would tell me how to do it this way. By the way I keep on get a little red line over  stuff.gettext so can some one please tell me the problem?

Comment: It's the other way around: stuff.getText().contains("!"). And `indexOf` can be used for single chars.

Comment: How about `if(stuff.getText().contains("!"))` instead?

Comment: Just wanted to say a BIG THANK YOU for everyone that has given me advice cause you were all right all along silly me stackoverflow rules!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are two main issues here:

- You are a little confused with the syntax
- Android often uses CharSequence for its text values, rather than String, so it makes it a bit more complicated.

Assuming "stuff" is your TextView, you can do the following:

```
String stuffText = stuff.getText().toString();
if(stuffText.contains("1")) {
    stuff.setText("Incorrect Symbol");
} else {

}
```

I'm not sure why you are getting the red line on stuff.getText(), but that line should have a corresponding compiler error that you can check in the appropriate view (assuming you're in an IDE like Eclipse).

And as for overall design, this is a bad way to go.  You can specify what characters the field accepts by setting up the XML:

```
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone|numberSigned"
    android:digits="0123456789" />
```

If you really want to have the feedback, you may want to use [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html), so you can respond as the user types.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[String.contains("yourCharacter")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)** to check if yourCharacter is present in the String or not.

So, your code will look like

```
if (stuff.getText().contains("!")) {
    stuff.setText("Incorrect Symbol"); // your text contains the symbol
}else {
    ..... // your text does not contain the symbol
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if it has just a "1" in it -- that is, all that is entered is a "1" -- then you'd want to use an `equals`, not a contains.

Assuming that `stuff.getText()` returns the inputted text:

```
if("1".equals(stuff.getText())) {
    // we'll end up here if the only thing in the input is 1
} else {
    // otherwise we'll end up here
}
```

For letters, you'll want to use `equalsIgnoreCase` for a case insensitive comparison.

If you want to check that the input *contains* a character, you'll use the `contains` method instead of equals:

```
if(stuff.getText().contains("1")) {
    // we end up here if the input text contains 1 somewhere in it
} else {
    // otherwise we'll end up here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(stuff.gettext().toString().contains("!") {
    stuff.setText("Incorrect Symbol");
} else {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if (stuff.getText().contains("!"))
```

or

```
if(stuff.getText().indexOf("!") != -1)
```

Since `indexOf` will return `-1` if the given char is not in the string.

As mentioned above, `indexOf` takes a single character as an argument, so if you want to see if a string contains a certain substring, use `contains`.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29):

> Returns: the index of the first occurrence of the character in the
>   character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character
>   does not occur.

Comment: I think it's supposed to look like (stuff.getText().contains("!")) and I keep on getting that red squigly line over the .contains any advice?

Comment: @vhkjgck getText() returns an `Editable`. So you want to do a `getText.toString()`

Comment: @vhkjgck Remember to read the errors you get. They're usually not vague in Java/Android/Eclipse.